# MPAndroidChart plots no data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm currently developing my first Android app ever. I need to visualize some data, and I've choosen MPAndroidChart v2.2.0 for this purpose (no special reason at all, it just looked right).

However, i'v created a LinedDataSet with 150 data points and also 150 x values, I combined these in a LineData Object and set this as data for the chart. Basically I just went through the documentation and performed the steps with my own data.

```
        mChart = (LineChart) myView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
// create data
        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<PDSDataService.SampleProxyObject> sampleIT = sampleList.getSamplesList().iterator();

        while(sampleIT.hasNext())
        {
            PDSDataService.SampleProxyObject sample = sampleIT.next();

            Entry smp = new Entry((float)sample.getRawValues(0).getValue(),(int)sample.getSampleID());

            values.add(smp);
            xVals.add(String.valueOf(sample.getSampleID()));

        }


        LineDataSet setParam1 = new LineDataSet(values, mlistItem.toString());

        LineData data = new LineData(xVals,setParam1);

        mChart.setData(data);

        mChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
        mChart.invalidate();
```

Now, when I start the app in an AVD, The chart shows up (btw, it's in a fragment, if this is important), the X and Y Axis is correctly scaled, but in the chart, nothing shows up, no line or something.

What have I done wrong? I was not able to test the App on a real device yet, might this issue be AVD related?

Comment: post your code please, there could be a number of reasons.

Comment: this has an example how to add a pie chart, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528848/listview-with-a-mpandroidchartor-whatever-below/34529166#34529166

Comment: Hi, I updated the post with more code. This is all performed in onCreateView of a fragment

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question was still unanswered so i tried to reproduce it myself.

I basically did exactly what you did, crate a Fragment and the Chart like you. The only difference is my data. I created 150 Values as well (just to test if this is anyhow too much or something), but just used a `List<float>` for ease.

My code looks like this:

```
    LineChart mChart = (LineChart) v.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
    list.add(0.1f); 
    // loop until you have added 150 values
    list.add(2.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Entry smp = new Entry(list.get(i),i);
        values.add(smp);
        xVals.add(String.valueOf("Test "+i));
    }

    LineDataSet setParam1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Anything");
    LineData data = new LineData(xVals,setParam1);
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
    mChart.invalidate();
```

For me it worked in the Simulator.

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Are you sure your Iterator and Data are correct?